# CSS Grid: Make nav bar collapsible in mobile

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Trying my best to learn CSS Grid...
I have made a nav menu but cannot get it to collapse for mobile view ('hamburger' menu style). I have tried using the 'checkbox hack' seen in several videos and online tutorials. 
I also can't seem to get all of the links to list (list begins at 'Products' in my mobile view, but should begin at 'About Us').

Been working on this for days with no luck.

If anyone could help me out in getting this to work I would be very grateful.

Here's the HTML & CSS:

```css
html, body{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
     font-size: 100%;
}
 header{
    /* grid-column-start: 1;
     grid-column-end: 3;
     grid-row:1;
     */
     grid-area: header;
     background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)), url(../img/rockspiral.jpg);
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat (4, 1fr);
    /* 100px, 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    */
    /**** Change to 10% and 90% otherwise it takes up the full viewport ****/
     grid-template-rows: 100px auto;
     grid-template-areas: "logo topbar-nav topbar-nav topbar-nav" ". hero-text hero-text . ";
}
 .logo{
     grid-area: logo;
     background-image:url(../img/logo-mobile.png);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     margin-left: 10px;
}
 .topbar-nav{
     grid-area: topbar-nav;
     color:white;
     background-color: lightblue;
     justify-self: end;
     align-self: center;
}
 .topbar-nav, ul, li{
     list-style-type: none;
     float: left;
     padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
 .hero-text{
     grid-area: hero-text;
     color:white;
     justify-self: center;
     align-self: center;
}
 .hero-text h1{
     font-size: 600%;
}
 .hero-text p{
     font-size: 200%;
     text-align: center;
}
 nav{
     grid-area: nav;
}
 .grid-about{
    /* grid-column-start: 1;
     grid-column-end: 4;
     grid-row:2;
    */
     grid-area: about;
}
 .grid-products{
    /* grid-column-start: 1;
     grid-column-end: 4;
     grid-row:3;
    */
     grid-area: products;
}
 .grid-services{
    /* grid-column-start: 1;
     grid-column-end: 4;
     grid-row:4;
     */
     grid-area: services;
}
 .grid-contact{
     grid-area: contact;
}
 .grid-location{
     grid-area: location;
}
 .grid-phone-social{
     grid-area: phone;
}
 footer{
    /* grid-column-start: 1;
     grid-column-end: 4;
     grid-row:6;
    */
     grid-area: footer;
}
/****Grid for mobile screens****/
 @media (max-width: 767px){
     .grid-container{
         display: grid;
         background-color: aqua;
         grid-auto-rows: 50vh;
         grid-gap: 10px;
         grid-template-areas: "header" 
        /* "nav"*/
         "about" "products" "services" "contact" "location" "phone" "footer";
    }
     header{
         background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)), url(../img/rockspiral-mobile.jpg);
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
        /* Change to: grid-template-columns: 110px auto;
        */
         grid-template-columns: 110px auto;
         grid-template-rows: 50px auto;
         grid-template-areas: "logo topbar-nav" "hero-text hero-text";
    }
     .topbar-nav ul, li{
         display: grid;
         grid-template-rows: 10px;
         grid-gap: 5px;
         font-size:75%;
         float:left;
    }
     .hero-text h1{
         font-size: 300%;
         text-align: center;
    }
     .hero-text p{
         font-size: 150%;
         text-align: center;
    }
}
/****Grid for tablet screens****/
 @media (min-width: 768px){
     .grid-container{
         display: grid;
         grid-auto-rows: 100vh;
         grid-gap: 10px;
         background-color: red;
         grid-template-areas: "header" 
        /* "nav" */
         "about" "products" "services" "contact" "location" "phone" "footer";
    }
     header{
         grid-area: header;
         background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)), url(../img/rockspiral.jpg);
         display: grid;
        /* changed: column size 260px 1fr 1fr 1fr*/
         grid-template-columns: 260px 1fr 1fr 1fr;
         grid-template-rows: 100px auto;
         grid-template-areas: "logo topbar-nav topbar-nav topbar-nav" "hero-text hero-text hero-text hero-text";
    }
     .logo{
         grid-area: logo;
         background-image:url(../img/logo.png);
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         margin-left: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang=en>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>CSS Grid Sandbox</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="grid-container">

        <header>

            <div class="logo"></div>

            <div class="topbar-nav">

                <ul>

                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Products</li>
                    <li>Services</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                    <li>Location & Hours</li>
                    <li>Phone & Social Media</li>

                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="hero-text">

                <h1>Big Rock Sale</h1>
                <p>All rocks 50% off. Offer ends soon!</p>

            </div>

        </header>

        <!--  <nav>Nav</nav>  -->

        <section class="grid-about">About Us</section>

        <section class="grid-products">Products</section>

        <section class="grid-services">Services</section>

        <section class="grid-contact">Contact</section>

        <section class="grid-location">Location & Hours</section>

        <section class="grid-phone-social">Phone & Social Media</section>

        <footer>Footer</footer>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: from my understanding you want an elements `display` property to switch between `hidden` and `block` when a user clicks on a button. While I believe that this can be achieved with pure CSS and HTML it is much easier when you throw a little Javascript into the mix.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I've also tried several tutorials that use the hidden/block switch with javascript with no luck. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

While I personally recommend using Javascript for this a pure CSS version can be achieved through multiple methods, one of which is by using a checkbox paired with the `:checked` selector.

```css
.hamburger-menu-content {
  display: none;
}

#hamburger-menu-trigger:checked+.hamburger-menu-content {
  /* '+' means all elements that have the first element preceding it */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="hamburger-menu-trigger">
<div class="hamburger-menu-content">
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
</div>
```

The downside of this approach is that you need to click the input again to close it.
To mitigate this we could use a pair of radio button.

```css
.hamburger-menu-content {
  display: none;
}
#hamburger-menu-trigger:checked {
  display: none;
}
#hamburger-menu-trigger:checked+.hamburger-menu-content {
  /* '+' means all elements that have the first element preceding it */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="menuToggle" id="hamburger-menu-trigger">
<div class="hamburger-menu-content">
  <input type="radio" name="menuToggle">
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
  <p>Foo</p>
</div>
```

edit: In case you want to change the looks of the buttons you can reference this guide https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but unfortunately, CSS grid seems to be interfering with this. I copied and pasted your code, and the only thing I changed were the number of p tags (your example had 3, I will need 6). With the CSS in place, the live preview only shows 4 p tags max, and when clicked, the radio checkbox button disappears and I cannot get it back unless I refresh the page.

Comment: It could very well be that your existing styles interfere with what I quickly cobbled together, fortunately you can use your browsers developer tools to look at the styles applied to elements. You can find these by doing a right click and selecting `inspect element` or hitting `ctrl+shift+i`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.